# Android app development - Native crash Randomly --Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

I created the application which connects socket to get some data, this application needs to non-stop to running and refresh data when getting web socket broadcast.

But when the application runs around 12-15 hours, the application has been a native crash and the message showed that `ubsan: add-overflow`.

I already update the android studio, NDK, SDK to latest version, but the problem still present, I have no idea to fix this problem and the bug location.

**Error Message:**

```
2020-03-24 18:16:46.999 4111-4111/com.example.myappname A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 4111 (le.myappname), pid 4111 (le.myappname)
2020-03-24 18:16:47.151 28648-28648/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2020-03-24 18:16:47.152 3331-3331/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 4111
2020-03-24 18:16:47.154 28648-28648/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 4111 (target tid = 4111)
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Amlogic/franklin/franklin:9/PPR1.180610.011/20191204:userdebug/test-keys'
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4111, tid: 4111, name: le.myappname  >>> com.example.myappname <<<
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  0000100f  r2  00000006  r3  ac656918
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     r4  0000100f  r5  0000100f  r6  bbc64eac  r7  0000010c
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     r8  bbc64f90  r9  00000001  r10 00000000  r11 00000000
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     ip  00000041  sp  bbc64e98  lr  ac5e50e5  pc  ac5dce72
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001ce72  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+62)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00016bc4  /system/lib/libminikin.so (abort_with_message(char const*)+24)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00016c20  /system/lib/libminikin.so (__ubsan_handle_add_overflow_minimal_abort+24)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000f2ef  /system/lib/libminikin.so (void minikin::LayoutCache::getOrCreate<minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor>(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, bool, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor&)+542)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000edf1  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutWord(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutPieces const*, minikin::Layout*, float*, minikin::MinikinExtent*, minikin::MinikinRect*, minikin::LayoutPieces*)+204)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000e999  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayoutRunCached(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, bool, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, unsigned int, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit, minikin::LayoutPieces const*, minikin::Layout*, float*, minikin::MinikinExtent*, minikin::MinikinRect*, minikin::LayoutPieces*)+244)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000e86b  /system/lib/libminikin.so (minikin::Layout::doLayout(minikin::U16StringPiece const&, minikin::Range const&, minikin::Bidi, minikin::MinikinPaint const&, minikin::StartHyphenEdit, minikin::EndHyphenEdit)+210)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00088ef1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::MinikinUtils::doLayout(android::Paint const*, minikin::Bidi, android::Typeface const*, unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, minikin::MeasuredText*)+148)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 003718ad  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::Canvas::drawText(unsigned short const*, int, int, int, float, float, minikin::Bidi, android::Paint const&, android::Typeface const*, minikin::MeasuredText*)+76)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000c8fc5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::drawTextChars(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long long, _jcharArray*, int, int, float, float, int, long long)+84)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 003b006b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawText [DEDUPED]+194)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00024a33  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawText+330)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000340bb  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.graphics.Canvas.drawText+66)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000232e7  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.text.Layout.drawText+2302)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000360f1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.text.Layout.draw+168)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0001de63  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.widget.TextView.onDraw+2962)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00032861  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+232)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.719 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 0003ae0b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild+50)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 0003de23  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw+42)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.720 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 00046ebd  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.draw+44)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 000244ef  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3478)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 000244d9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+3456)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 0003274f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild+54)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 00033a89  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw+1296)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 00032875  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.View.draw+252)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.721 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 0004c841  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw+40)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 00046a07  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware+758)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 00043125  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw+2028)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 0004b7a1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw+336)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 000541bb  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals+10674)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 0005610f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal+150)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 00056931  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run+48)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 00042403  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run+186)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 0003d2b9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks+496)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 00043f2f  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer.doFrame+934)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 00055f0d  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run+68)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 00050f65  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+52)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 00056e83  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+58)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #86 pc 0006a1cd  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Looper.loop+892)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #87 pc 00417dbb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+42)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #88 pc 0024ea41  /system/lib/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::MaybeDoOnStackReplacement(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, int, art::JValue*)+1464)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #89 pc 003f08e7  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpMaybeDoOnStackReplacement+86)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #90 pc 004174f4  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+66164)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #91 pc 00aea584  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+928)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #92 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #93 pc 001cc757  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+146)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #94 pc 001e34fb  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+754)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #95 pc 003eceeb  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+130)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #96 pc 0040ab94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #97 pc 00384aa2  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.app.ActivityThread.main+214)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #98 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #99 pc 001cc6a3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.722 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #100 pc 003df753  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+890)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #101 pc 0041c2ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #102 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #103 pc 003f13eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #104 pc 000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #105 pc 00350a6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #106 pc 00351eb5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+960)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #107 pc 00302bd9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+40)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #108 pc 001121ff  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x10c000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+110)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #109 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #110 pc 003f12e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+226)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #111 pc 000a1031  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+136)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #112 pc 001e8835  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+232)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #113 pc 001e3511  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+776)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #114 pc 003ebf0f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+442)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #115 pc 0040aa14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #116 pc 00c0b146  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+22)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #117 pc 001c7e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2193211614+352)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #118 pc 001cc6a3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+82)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #119 pc 003df753  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+890)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #120 pc 0041c2ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+30)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #121 pc 00a10ad1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2896)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #122 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #123 pc 003f13eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+222)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #124 pc 000a1043  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+154)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #125 pc 00350a6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #126 pc 00350889  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+304)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.723 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #127 pc 002949cd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+476)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #128 pc 0006cb73  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #129 pc 0006ed9b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+462)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #130 pc 0000198d  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+724)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #131 pc 00088f55  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #132 pc 00001677  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+46)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #133 pc 00019a27  /system/bin/linker (__dl__ZNSt3__112__hash_tableINS_17__hash_value_typeIjP6soinfoEENS_22__unordered_map_hasherIjS4_NS_4hashIjEELb1EEENS_21__unordered_map_equalIjS4_NS_8equal_toIjEELb1EEENS_9allocatorIS4_EEE14__erase_uniqueIjEEjRKT_+90)
2020-03-24 18:16:48.724 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG:     #134 pc 007fec5e  [stack:bb46b000]
2020-03-24 18:16:49.554 3331-3331/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
```

**Build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myappname"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.shuhart.stickyheader:stickyheader:1.0.6'
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.1.0-alpha1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'


}
```

Testing device :

Android 9.0, 
rooted, 
Android Studio 3.6.1

Please help me with the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this function

`minikin::LayoutCache::getOrCreate<minikin::LayoutAppendFunctor>`

in this function, you might be doing addition operation with a large value, and the result value might be bigger than the storage size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem on the hardware side. This is evidenced by the line:

```
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
```

OTA version :

```
2020-03-24 18:16:47.176 28648-28648/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Amlogic/franklin/franklin:9/PPR1.180610.011/20191204:userdebug/test-keys'
```

DEVICE:

```
PPR1.180610.011 - Google Pixel 2 (9.0.0 (PPR1.180610.011, Aug 2018, Telstra))
```

Version OTA:

```
20191204
```

OTA update should help!